# JAX-RS: Testing @Provider annotated Classes

Tags: java, jax-rs, mockito

When I try to create a new Object from a Class (annotated with @Provider) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at xx.xxx.xxx.mapper.AExceptionMapper.<clinit>(AExceptionMapper.java:16)
```

The Provider looks like:

```
@Provider
public class AExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Blupp>
```

Same if trying to get a Mock via Mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, there ware other Errors hidden by this one. After getting Netbeans and Maven back to show them directly and after fixin, the error above disappears